# Flutter - Navigating to detail page on a sfdatagrid row selection (table has data fromfirestore)

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web, syncfusion, sfdatagrid

I managed to populate a SfDatagrid table with data from firestore, this is the link to the code:

[https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/How-to-load-data-from-firestore-to-Flutter-DataTable-SfDataGrid-](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

This code is running perfectly and I have the desired result.

But the problem is that on a table selection I want the app to navigate on a detail page and show more info from the firebase source on the selected row.

But I don't know how I can pass the document snapshot or document index to the detail page when row is selected.

Notice that I am not a pro yet, I'm just getting started.

I tried this:

```
onCellTap: (DataGridCellTapDetails details) {

              final DataGridRow row = employeeDataGridSource
                 .effectiveRows[details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1];
              Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => DataGridRowInfoPage(row: row)));

            },
```

But it only shows the info on the table, but on the firestore document I have a lots of field and I can't show them all on a table, I wish to show them only on detail page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the document index by finding the tapped **DataGridRow** from the **DataGridSource.effectiveRows** property and then finding the **index** from the **DataGridSource.dataGridRows** property using that row. Now you can fetch the document details from the snapshot by using that index.

**Code Snippet:**

```dart
SfDataGrid(
            source: employeeDataSource,
            columns: getColumns,
            onCellTap: (details) {
              if (details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex != 0) {
                final DataGridRow row = employeeDataSource
                    .effectiveRows[details.rowColumnIndex.rowIndex - 1];
                int index = employeeDataSource.dataGridRows.indexOf(row);
                var data = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => DataGridRowInfoPage(data)));
              }
            },
          );
```

**In DataGridRowInfoPage:**

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataGridRowInfoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DataGridRowInfoPage(this.data, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?> data;

  @override
  DataGridRowInfoPageState createState() => DataGridRowInfoPageState();
}

class DataGridRowInfoPageState extends State<DataGridRowInfoPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter DataGrid'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Employee salary: ${widget.data.get('salary')}'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wowww... It's working perfectly fine. Thank you a million